# Controlling warnings qmake

Tags: qt, compilation

qmake generates a makefile from a qt project file (*.pro).  It is possible to control warnings by adding warn_on or warn_off to the CONFIG variable in the project file. warn_on sets the -Wall and -Wextra compiler flags. warn_off sets the -w compiler flag.

How can I configure qmake to only set the -Wall compliler flag? Or, how can I get rid of the -Wextra compiler flag?

I have tried 
CONFIG+= warn_off
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -Wall
but then the -w and the -Wall compiler flags are set, and -w overrides -Wall and I get no warnings.

I'm using Qt5.1 and gcc.

Comment: What's the default behavior without touching CONFIG or QMAKE_CXXFLAGS? For me it is exactly as you're looking for (i.e. only -Wall).

Comment: Without touching CONFIG or QMAKE_CXXFLAGS I get -Wall and -Wextra (Qt5.1). Just created a new project and compiled it. I expected the default behaviour to be -Wall, but it isn't.